# How can a flexbox / grid column be fixed to the top-right of the page?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have four navigation icons that I would like to display in a single column, coming down from the top-right corner of the page. I have tried to fix a div to the top-right but all of the elements just overlap directly on top of each other and don't align down the page as a column.

```
<a href="/home" class="navigation" >A</a>
<a href="/about" class="navigation">?</a>
<a href="/account" class="navigation"></a>

.navigation { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  font-size: 8vh; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 2vh; 
  right: 5vw; 
  z-index: 100; 
}
```

Can flexbox and a fixed div work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place them inside a container and add `display: flex` to it.
Something like:

```css
.container{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 2vh; 
  right: 5vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>item</a>
  <a>item</a>
  <a>item</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, use `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work: the elements are still overlapped on top of each other.

Comment: you'd need to post a bit more code (HTML and CSS), otherwise it's hard to tell *what*  doesn't work as expected

Comment: Ah ok, I've added the links. Thanks!

Comment: You need to post the whole surrounding HTML code, up to the parent container, plus all related CSS, not just three `a` tags...